# Changing playback speed in Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm looking to implement an audio player with variable speed playback (1.0x, 1.25x, 1.5x) like typical audiobook players currently on the market do. I would like to use Google's Exoplayer library as my audioplayer library however they don't appear to support variable speed playback. Any ideas on how to implement this, or any extensions that do support this?

Comment: UPDATE:

Just an updated on this for anyone still searching: Exoplayer has added this functionality baked into their API. Happy coding!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The function `setPlaybackSpeed()` was removed and now you set the playback speed via:

```
    PlaybackParameters param = new PlaybackParameters(speed);
    mExoPlayer.setPlaybackParameters(param);
```

`speed` is a float number. Normal speed is `1f` and double the speed would be `2f`.

Comment: Is this in real-time or load-time?

Comment: @Swapnil: I don't understand what you mean, can you be more specfici about your question?

Comment: I mean, can we change the pitch and tempo while the media is playing or we only specify ot when the audio is loaded.

Comment: Rate changes can be made during playback.

Comment: @Swapnil yes it is real-time speed

Answer (score 8):

### Kotlin Extension Solution

Make it easy to access and set this reliably across your app in Kotlin

```
// To set
player.playbackSpeed = 2f

var SimpleExoPlayer.playbackSpeed: Float
    get() = playbackParameters?.speed ?: 1f
    set(speed) {
        val pitch = playbackParameters?.pitch ?: 1f
        playbackParameters = PlaybackParameters(speed, pitch)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

All you need is https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic/blob/master/Sonic.java

If you look at **MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.java**,
you can get the output buffer (decoded by MediaCodec) from ExoPlayer in method **processOutputBuffer** and process it through **Sonic.java** accordingly before sending it to **AudioTrack**.

Following document explains how to use libsonic
https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: First, thanks for the response @T.J, appreciate it. So I did some Googling and found this 

https://github.com/skonb/MediaCodecSpeedControllableTrackRenderer/blob/master/MediaCodecSpeedControllableAudioTrackRenderer.java

Does this implementation look close to what you're talking about? I tried integrating it with the Exoplayer library and there doesn't appear to be any sound.

Comment: No problem. Yes, thats exactly what I was talking about. Not sure why there is no sound. I would say log processOutputBuffer to see whats happening with the data.

Answer (score 3):

## Try This

I have followed all the answer nothing worked, so i have tried the below solution, it works for me

```
PlaybackParams param = new PlaybackParams();
param.setSpeed(1f);// 1f is 1x, 2f is 2x 
exoPlayer.setPlaybackParams(param);
```

Comment: This solution will not work below 23 android version.

Answer (score 0):

in Exoplayer version `2.14.0`

Pass the `float` value directly like this.

```kotlin
simpleExoPlayer?.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f)
```

Answer (score -2):

You should take a look this project, which was very useful for me:
https://github.com/AmrMohammed89/exoplayer2.4.0_speedup

Inside SimpleExoPlayer, I implemented the next methods:

```
 private final ExoPlayer player;
private float playbackSpeed;

float SPEED_NORMAL = 1f;
float SPEED_MEDIUM = 1.5f;
float SPEED_HIGH = 2f;


 @Override
public float getPlaybackSpeed() {
    return playbackSpeed;
}

@Override
public void setPlaybackSpeed(float speed) {
    playbackSpeed = speed;
    player.setPlaybackSpeed(speed);
}

@Override
public void changePlaybackSpeed() {
    if (playbackSpeed == SPEED_MEDIUM) {
        player.setPlaybackSpeed(SPEED_HIGH);
        playbackSpeed = SPEED_HIGH;
    } else if (playbackSpeed == SPEED_HIGH) {
        player.setPlaybackSpeed(SPEED_NORMAL);
        playbackSpeed = SPEED_NORMAL;
    } else {
        player.setPlaybackSpeed(SPEED_MEDIUM);
        playbackSpeed = SPEED_MEDIUM;
    }
}
```

I set and saved the speed that way due to there was a bug when I tried to get the last saved speed. So follow that mechanism and it will work perfectly.

Cheers