# Support playback speed rate using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, mp4, exoplayer, audiovideoplayback

Does Exoplayer support playback speed changes in Video (MP4 and HLS) ?

If not, does anyone have a suggestion on how to implement this kind of feature ?

Comment: try to post this question on https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues

Comment: Hey buddy, take a look my comment which will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46003861/2606290